# Medusa connect to db per instructions is not connecting

Tags: medusajs

According to the documentation in two areas of the documentation:
Configurations/database_url:

```
postgres://[user][:password]@[host][:port]/[dbname]
```

You set the database url like so:

```
module.exports = {
  projectConfig: {
    database_url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

You can also Create Medusa App like so:

```
npx create-medusa-app@latest --db-url postgres://[user][:password]@[host][:port]/[dbname]
```

When I run either of the above with those exact settings:

```
npx create-medusa-app@latest --db-url postgres://impctUsr:password@164.90.xxx.xxx:5432/impactcolorDB
```

I get the errors:
`Couldn't connect to PostgreSQL using the database URL you passed. Make sure it's correct and try again.` or when just trying to migrate and having it configured in the .env

[![TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: postgres://impctUsr:password@164.90.xxx.xxx:5432/impactcolorDB][1]][1]

I can confirm that the credentials work from a local client connection.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcbm3.png

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by help from @shahednasser:
The password had special characters so I removed them.
I also added quotations around the string.

```
npx create-medusa-app@latest --db-url "postgres://impctUsr:passwordWithNoSpecialCharacters@164.90.xxx.xxx:5432/impactcolorDB"
```